# Absolute Coordinate Mismatch with Drawn Coordinate

Tags: android, graphics

I'm having a lot of trouble understanding what I'm doing wrong here.  I'm trying to draw a circle centered around where the user touches.  There seems to be a y-axis offset when the circle is drawn (pictures: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yeJD.png), [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KQIP.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErNzS.png).)  The cursor is the location where I "touch" the screen.  The green circle is plotting with event.getX and getY, while the red circle is event.getRawX() and getRawY().  I've looked some of the previous questions, and they usually recommend some sort of linear correction; as you can see, the offset seems to get worse as we get towards the top and bottom of the screen, and the offset is different for the two different coordinate system.  Here's my code for the project:

```
package com.example.dustylenz.albertlifinalproject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class GraphProject extends ActionBarActivity {
    private double screenWidth;
    private double screenHeight;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_graph_project);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_graph_project, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        private RelativeLayout graphLayout;
        private View.OnTouchListener graphListener;
        private Paint paint;
        private Canvas canvas;
        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_graph_project, container, false);
            graphLayout = (RelativeLayout)  rootView.findViewById(R.id.graphLayout);
            graphLayout.setPadding(0,0,0,0);


            paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#CD5C5C"));
            paint.setStrokeWidth(7);
            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            //Get Display Size
            Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            int width = size.x;
            int height = size.y;


            Bitmap bg = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            canvas = new Canvas(bg);
            graphLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bg));

            graphListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                        System.out.println("X: " + event.getX() + " Raw X: " + event.getRawX());
                        System.out.println("Y: " + event.getY() + " Raw Y: " + event.getRawY());
                        int[] temp = new int [2];
                        v.getLocationOnScreen(temp);
                        System.out.println("sdfadsf");
                        System.out.println("Window X: " + temp[0] + " Window Y: " + temp[1]);
                        System.out.println("View X: " + v.getX() + " View Y: " + v.getY());
                        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#CD5C5C"));
                        canvas.drawCircle(event.getRawX(), event.getRawY(), 50, paint);
                        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF7F"));
                        canvas.drawCircle(event.getX(), event.getY(), 50, paint);
                        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                        canvas.drawCircle(temp[0], temp[1], 50, paint);
                        graphLayout.invalidate();
                        // Do what you want
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            };

            graphLayout.setOnTouchListener(graphListener);

            return rootView;
        }

    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated! I've been at this for 5 or 6 hours and haven't made much progress.

Comment: I've confirmed that it's not an emulator issue; there's some differences between the real world touch and the canvas that I'm not catching.